# Haskell infinite loop in do block

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a program in Haskell to simulate combat between two players in D&D. The method I'm using is to store players as Maps, and then have 'attack' functions that take a Player, and return an IO Player with updated health, based on whether or not the attack connected. All of my code seems to be working as intended, up until the last function, `combat`. `combat` is supposed to take two players, have the first one attack the second, check if the second is dead, and if not, recur with the order of the players reversed. Instead, it appears to be looping infinitely.

The function itself is as follows -

```
combat :: Player -> Player -> IO String
combat a b = do
    damaged <- a `attacks` b
    nextRound <- combat damaged a
    return $ if (victor a damaged) /= "No victor yet" then (victor a damaged) else nextRound
```

The `attacks` function takes two players, checks the ID of the first one, and applies the appropriate sequence of attacks to the second one. It works just fine when I use it on its own in GHCi, so I don't think there's a problem there.

The `victor` function takes two players, checks if either of them is dead (defined as HP <= 0), and returns a string describing the result. When I wrote a toy version of `combat` without any recursion that just returned "test" when the condition wasn't met, it was returning a combination of "Player 1 wins!" and "test", so I don't think there's a problem there.

I did come across a similar looking question with let bindings, where somebody was running into an infinite loop when they had code like `let n = n + 1`, but I'm not sure if `<-` works in the same way (or, if it did, how else I could write it).

Comment: This code will never reach the `return` line. Each time you call `combat`, it will call itself with arguments reversed, but never complete because it will call itself again before having a chance to get past that line.

Comment: @PeterHall Alright, that makes sense. But, I get a type error when I put `combat damaged a` exclusively in the else statement (it wants a regular String, but it's getting an IO String), which is the problem I was trying to solve when I put the recursion above the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to do the termination check before you do the recursive step, or you will never be able to terminate. Here's a small reordering:

```
combat :: Player -> Player -> IO String
combat a b = do
    damaged <- a `attacks` b
    case victor a damaged of
      "No victor yet" -> combat damaged a
      winner -> return winner
```

Note that this would be much nicer if `victor` returned `Maybe String` instead, so that you wouldn't depend on this magical string `"No victor yet"`. Then you could write:

```
combat :: Player -> Player -> IO String
combat a b = do
    damaged <- a `attacks` b
    case victor a damaged of
      Nothing -> combat damaged a
      Just winner -> return winner
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try to post minimum compile-able examples in the future.

As stated in the comments, calling `combat` unconditionally from within the body of `combat` is a non-starter.  Instead, sink it down into the proper arm of the if-then-else.

You also mentioned you had a type error when placing `combat` in one of the cases.  I'm guessing you were using `return $ if ...` which means either branch will be wrapped in another layer of `IO ...` but your `combat` is already of of type `IO _`.

```
combat :: Player -> Player -> IO String
combat a b = do
    damaged <- a `attacks` b
    if (victor a damaged) /= "No victor yet"
         then return (victor a damaged)
         else combat damaged a
```

Now there are two other warts.  One is the repeated statement calling `victor`.  The other is using string comparison to determine program flow, ugh!  Instead how about you make `victor` return a ADT?

```
data Status = Dead String | Alive

combat :: Player -> Player -> IO String
combat a b = do
    damaged <- a `attacks` b
    case victor a damaged of
        Alive  -> combat damaged a
        Dead s -> return s
```